# Concatenate incrementing row number with string in Google Sheets Arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get a column to automatically fill up with incrementing strings depending on the row number in an `ARRAYFORMULA` in Google sheets. I can easily get a column to show a shifted row number by putting `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)-1)` in the top cell. However trying to use this `ROW` call inside `CONCATENATE` does not give me the result I want, I've tried with and without `TO_TEXT`.

In the image the formula used for the different columns are:

**A1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)-1)`

**B1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B1:B)>1,CONCATENATE("Hello World: ",(ROW()-1)),"Hello there world!"))`

**C1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(C1:C)>1,CONCATENATE("Hello World: ",TO_TEXT(ROW(C:C)-1)),"Hello there world!"))`

**D1:D16:** *Manually entered the desired strings.*

[Spreadsheet screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwrGX.png)

As you can see, **B1** doesn't increment the number, only uses the `ROW` value from the cell where the formula is given. And **C1** concatenates all the numbers of the rows into every line.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish the intended result without filling or using scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an unwritten rule that says to never use `CONCATENATE` unless you really need it which is also always never. to join stuff all you need is `&`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Hello there world!"; "Hello World: "&ROW(A2:A)-1})
```

Answer (score 0):

In B1 try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B:B)>1, "Hello World: "&ROW(B:B)-1,"Hello there world!"))
```

or

```
={"Hello there world!"; ARRAYFORMULA("Hello World: "&ROW(B2:B)-1)}
```

and see if that works?